# Spring Cloud Dataflow Server Lock the Jar Locally

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am designing the batch workflow with SCDF on Windows OS. When I test the code on my local machine, I deploy and run the Spring batch job jar locally by registering the jar using file URL. The problem is that whenever I want to rebuild my batch job jar, I cannot delete the jar that has already registered on the SCDF server as the OS warned me that the jar is being used by a Java program (even when the batch job is not running at that time).

It is quite inconvenient for developers to shut down the SCDF server every time when they want to rebuild the jar and replace the existing jar. Is there any workaround, or am I missing any configuration?

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this is an inconvenience but unfortunately this is expected when using `file://` based resources. One alternative is to install your app as maven artifact in your local and refer them as `maven://` based resources.